# CamanJS Filters to Photoshop Curves

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, photoshop, camanjs

Is there a way to obtain the photoshop curves of a CamanJS filter?

for example:

```
Caman.Filter.register("hemingway", function() {
this.greyscale();
this.contrast(10);
this.gamma(0.9);
this.newLayer(function() {
  this.setBlendingMode("multiply");
  this.opacity(40);
  this.copyParent();
  this.filter.exposure(15);
  this.filter.contrast(15);
  return this.filter.channels({
    green: 10,
    red: 5
  });
});
this.sepia(30);
this.curves('rgb', [0, 10], [120, 90], [180, 200], [235, 255]);
this.channels({
  red: 5,
  green: -2
});
return this.exposure(15);
});
```

I tried to use those curves values, but don't seem to be the same.

Any insight?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is that camanjs uses Bezier curves for its curve() method, while Photoshop uses something like a Cardinal spline or a simpler Catmull-Rom spline (splines which passes through the actual points).

For this reason it will also be complex to convert the Bezier control points to a cardinal spline, and vice versa.

You can make a mapping interface so you can draw the Bezier, then provide points for a cardinal spline, move them around so that they closely matches the curve made by the Bezier, and use those for Photoshop. I have made an [cardinal spline implementation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15528789/1693593), there may be others out there if you feel this could be one way of solving it.

But in general, you would have to convert between the two types.

**Update**

**[This code (not JS but C) (FitCurves.c)](https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gems/FitCurves.c)** may or may not help you with curve-fitting the Bezier. C and JS are closely related syntax-wise so it should be easy to translate.

Hope this helps.