# Canvas drawing using query/angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, canvas

Here's what I'm trying to achieve. Draw a circle(first circle) on the screen on a mouse click. Then draw successive circles on successive mouse clicks and connect each to the first circle.

I've managed to get till here.

Now the task is if any of the circles have the same y-coordinate as the first one, the connection is a straight line, else it should be a s-curve/inverted s-curve depending on whether the next circle is above or below the first one based on its y-axis.

It may be assumed that all successive circle will be on the right of the first circle.

Here's my code

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {


    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
    var cw=canvas.width;
    var ch=canvas.height;

    function reOffset(){
      var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      offsetX=BB.left;
      offsetY=BB.top;        
    }
    var offsetX,offsetY;
    reOffset();
    window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }

    var isDown=false;
    var startX,startY;

    var radius=10;
    var lastX,lastY;

    ctx.fillStyle='red';


  $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});


    function drawCircle(cx,cy){
      if(lastX){
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation='destination-over';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);
        ctx.lineTo(cx,cy);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
      }else{
        lastX=cx;
        lastY=cy;
      }
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.fill();
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      // tell the browser we're handling this event
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      mx=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      my=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

      drawCircle(mx,my);
    }

});
```

Here's a link to the plunk that will demonstrate the behavior

http://plnkr.co/edit/rYVLgB14IutNh1F4MN6T?p=preview

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly which kind of s-curve are you interested in. As I understand it will be always only two points to connect, the first point and the rest, and you are looking for some sort of quadratic curve to do so. Under this situation you can build a s-curve by joining two ctx.quadraticCurveTo calls.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);

ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
  (lastX+cx)/2, lastY,
  (lastX+cx)/2, (lastY+cy)/2
);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(
  (lastX+cx)/2, cy,
  cx, cy
);

ctx.lineWidth = 3;
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/t10cMPcUtX5ifkWi2LBF?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

To make each of your connectors avoid existing circles, you must use a pathfinding algorithm (A* for example).

Pathfinding algorithms will give you a set of points from Circle1 to Circle2 that avoid all other circles.

Then you can use that set of points to build a connector between those circles using a Spline. See this very good answer by Stackoverflow's Ken Fyrstenberg on how to draw a spline. Make sure you keep the tension on the spline tight (closer to zero) so that your spline connector doesn't stray too far from the unobstructed path:

[how to draw smooth curve through N points using javascript HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054272/how-to-draw-smooth-curve-through-n-points-using-javascript-html5-canvas/15528789#15528789)

This is a nice script implementing the A* algorithm by Brian Grinstead:

https://github.com/bgrins/javascript-astar/

And here's a Demo of Brian Grinstead's A* script:

http://www.briangrinstead.com/files/astar/

To avoid a link-only answer, I'm attaching Brian's script from GitHub below...

But seriously...if GitHub disappears many of us subscribers are in trouble!

```
// javascript-astar 0.4.0
// http://github.com/bgrins/javascript-astar
// Freely distributable under the MIT License.
// Implements the astar search algorithm in javascript using a Binary Heap.
// Includes Binary Heap (with modifications) from Marijn Haverbeke.
// http://eloquentjavascript.net/appendix2.html

(function(definition) {
    /* global module, define */
    if(typeof module === 'object' && typeof module.exports === 'object') {
        module.exports = definition();
    } else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define([], definition);
    } else {
        var exports = definition();
        window.astar = exports.astar;
        window.Graph = exports.Graph;
    }
})(function() {

function pathTo(node){
    var curr = node,
        path = [];
    while(curr.parent) {
        path.push(curr);
        curr = curr.parent;
    }
    return path.reverse();
}

function getHeap() {
    return new BinaryHeap(function(node) {
        return node.f;
    });
}

var astar = {
    /**
    * Perform an A* Search on a graph given a start and end node.
    * @param {Graph} graph
    * @param {GridNode} start
    * @param {GridNode} end
    * @param {Object} [options]
    * @param {bool} [options.closest] Specifies whether to return the
               path to the closest node if the target is unreachable.
    * @param {Function} [options.heuristic] Heuristic function (see
    *          astar.heuristics).
    */
    search: function(graph, start, end, options) {
        graph.cleanDirty();
        options = options || {};
        var heuristic = options.heuristic || astar.heuristics.manhattan,
            closest = options.closest || false;

        var openHeap = getHeap(),
            closestNode = start; // set the start node to be the closest if required

        start.h = heuristic(start, end);

        openHeap.push(start);

        while(openHeap.size() > 0) {

            // Grab the lowest f(x) to process next.  Heap keeps this sorted for us.
            var currentNode = openHeap.pop();

            // End case -- result has been found, return the traced path.
            if(currentNode === end) {
                return pathTo(currentNode);
            }

            // Normal case -- move currentNode from open to closed, process each of its neighbors.
            currentNode.closed = true;

            // Find all neighbors for the current node.
            var neighbors = graph.neighbors(currentNode);

            for (var i = 0, il = neighbors.length; i < il; ++i) {
                var neighbor = neighbors[i];

                if (neighbor.closed || neighbor.isWall()) {
                    // Not a valid node to process, skip to next neighbor.
                    continue;
                }

                // The g score is the shortest distance from start to current node.
                // We need to check if the path we have arrived at this neighbor is the shortest one we have seen yet.
                var gScore = currentNode.g + neighbor.getCost(currentNode),
                    beenVisited = neighbor.visited;

                if (!beenVisited || gScore < neighbor.g) {

                    // Found an optimal (so far) path to this node.  Take score for node to see how good it is.
                    neighbor.visited = true;
                    neighbor.parent = currentNode;
                    neighbor.h = neighbor.h || heuristic(neighbor, end);
                    neighbor.g = gScore;
                    neighbor.f = neighbor.g + neighbor.h;
                    graph.markDirty(neighbor);
                    if (closest) {
                        // If the neighbour is closer than the current closestNode or if it's equally close but has
                        // a cheaper path than the current closest node then it becomes the closest node
                        if (neighbor.h < closestNode.h || (neighbor.h === closestNode.h && neighbor.g < closestNode.g)) {
                            closestNode = neighbor;
                        }
                    }

                    if (!beenVisited) {
                        // Pushing to heap will put it in proper place based on the 'f' value.
                        openHeap.push(neighbor);
                    }
                    else {
                        // Already seen the node, but since it has been rescored we need to reorder it in the heap
                        openHeap.rescoreElement(neighbor);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (closest) {
            return pathTo(closestNode);
        }

        // No result was found - empty array signifies failure to find path.
        return [];
    },
    // See list of heuristics: http://theory.stanford.edu/~amitp/GameProgramming/Heuristics.html
    heuristics: {
        manhattan: function(pos0, pos1) {
            var d1 = Math.abs(pos1.x - pos0.x);
            var d2 = Math.abs(pos1.y - pos0.y);
            return d1 + d2;
        },
        diagonal: function(pos0, pos1) {
            var D = 1;
            var D2 = Math.sqrt(2);
            var d1 = Math.abs(pos1.x - pos0.x);
            var d2 = Math.abs(pos1.y - pos0.y);
            return (D * (d1 + d2)) + ((D2 - (2 * D)) * Math.min(d1, d2));
        }
    },
    cleanNode:function(node){
        node.f = 0;
        node.g = 0;
        node.h = 0;
        node.visited = false;
        node.closed = false;
        node.parent = null;
    }
};

/**
* A graph memory structure
* @param {Array} gridIn 2D array of input weights
* @param {Object} [options]
* @param {bool} [options.diagonal] Specifies whether diagonal moves are allowed
*/
function Graph(gridIn, options) {
    options = options || {};
    this.nodes = [];
    this.diagonal = !!options.diagonal;
    this.grid = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < gridIn.length; x++) {
        this.grid[x] = [];

        for (var y = 0, row = gridIn[x]; y < row.length; y++) {
            var node = new GridNode(x, y, row[y]);
            this.grid[x][y] = node;
            this.nodes.push(node);
        }
    }
    this.init();
}

Graph.prototype.init = function() {
    this.dirtyNodes = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
        astar.cleanNode(this.nodes[i]);
    }
};

Graph.prototype.cleanDirty = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.dirtyNodes.length; i++) {
        astar.cleanNode(this.dirtyNodes[i]);
    }
    this.dirtyNodes = [];
};

Graph.prototype.markDirty = function(node) {
    this.dirtyNodes.push(node);
};

Graph.prototype.neighbors = function(node) {
    var ret = [],
        x = node.x,
        y = node.y,
        grid = this.grid;

    // West
    if(grid[x-1] && grid[x-1][y]) {
        ret.push(grid[x-1][y]);
    }

    // East
    if(grid[x+1] && grid[x+1][y]) {
        ret.push(grid[x+1][y]);
    }

    // South
    if(grid[x] && grid[x][y-1]) {
        ret.push(grid[x][y-1]);
    }

    // North
    if(grid[x] && grid[x][y+1]) {
        ret.push(grid[x][y+1]);
    }

    if (this.diagonal) {
        // Southwest
        if(grid[x-1] && grid[x-1][y-1]) {
            ret.push(grid[x-1][y-1]);
        }

        // Southeast
        if(grid[x+1] && grid[x+1][y-1]) {
            ret.push(grid[x+1][y-1]);
        }

        // Northwest
        if(grid[x-1] && grid[x-1][y+1]) {
            ret.push(grid[x-1][y+1]);
        }

        // Northeast
        if(grid[x+1] && grid[x+1][y+1]) {
            ret.push(grid[x+1][y+1]);
        }
    }

    return ret;
};

Graph.prototype.toString = function() {
    var graphString = [],
        nodes = this.grid, // when using grid
        rowDebug, row, y, l;
    for (var x = 0, len = nodes.length; x < len; x++) {
        rowDebug = [];
        row = nodes[x];
        for (y = 0, l = row.length; y < l; y++) {
            rowDebug.push(row[y].weight);
        }
        graphString.push(rowDebug.join(" "));
    }
    return graphString.join("\n");
};

function GridNode(x, y, weight) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.weight = weight;
}

GridNode.prototype.toString = function() {
    return "[" + this.x + " " + this.y + "]";
};

GridNode.prototype.getCost = function(fromNeighbor) {
    // Take diagonal weight into consideration.
    if (fromNeighbor && fromNeighbor.x != this.x && fromNeighbor.y != this.y) {
        return this.weight * 1.41421;
    }
    return this.weight;
};

GridNode.prototype.isWall = function() {
    return this.weight === 0;
};

function BinaryHeap(scoreFunction){
    this.content = [];
    this.scoreFunction = scoreFunction;
}

BinaryHeap.prototype = {
    push: function(element) {
        // Add the new element to the end of the array.
        this.content.push(element);

        // Allow it to sink down.
        this.sinkDown(this.content.length - 1);
    },
    pop: function() {
        // Store the first element so we can return it later.
        var result = this.content[0];
        // Get the element at the end of the array.
        var end = this.content.pop();
        // If there are any elements left, put the end element at the
        // start, and let it bubble up.
        if (this.content.length > 0) {
            this.content[0] = end;
            this.bubbleUp(0);
        }
        return result;
    },
    remove: function(node) {
        var i = this.content.indexOf(node);

        // When it is found, the process seen in 'pop' is repeated
        // to fill up the hole.
        var end = this.content.pop();

        if (i !== this.content.length - 1) {
            this.content[i] = end;

            if (this.scoreFunction(end) < this.scoreFunction(node)) {
                this.sinkDown(i);
            }
            else {
                this.bubbleUp(i);
            }
        }
    },
    size: function() {
        return this.content.length;
    },
    rescoreElement: function(node) {
        this.sinkDown(this.content.indexOf(node));
    },
    sinkDown: function(n) {
        // Fetch the element that has to be sunk.
        var element = this.content[n];

        // When at 0, an element can not sink any further.
        while (n > 0) {

            // Compute the parent element's index, and fetch it.
            var parentN = ((n + 1) >> 1) - 1,
                parent = this.content[parentN];
            // Swap the elements if the parent is greater.
            if (this.scoreFunction(element) < this.scoreFunction(parent)) {
                this.content[parentN] = element;
                this.content[n] = parent;
                // Update 'n' to continue at the new position.
                n = parentN;
            }
            // Found a parent that is less, no need to sink any further.
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    },
    bubbleUp: function(n) {
        // Look up the target element and its score.
        var length = this.content.length,
            element = this.content[n],
            elemScore = this.scoreFunction(element);

        while(true) {
            // Compute the indices of the child elements.
            var child2N = (n + 1) << 1,
                child1N = child2N - 1;
            // This is used to store the new position of the element, if any.
            var swap = null,
                child1Score;
            // If the first child exists (is inside the array)...
            if (child1N < length) {
                // Look it up and compute its score.
                var child1 = this.content[child1N];
                child1Score = this.scoreFunction(child1);

                // If the score is less than our element's, we need to swap.
                if (child1Score < elemScore){
                    swap = child1N;
                }
            }

            // Do the same checks for the other child.
            if (child2N < length) {
                var child2 = this.content[child2N],
                    child2Score = this.scoreFunction(child2);
                if (child2Score < (swap === null ? elemScore : child1Score)) {
                    swap = child2N;
                }
            }

            // If the element needs to be moved, swap it, and continue.
            if (swap !== null) {
                this.content[n] = this.content[swap];
                this.content[swap] = element;
                n = swap;
            }
            // Otherwise, we are done.
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

return {
    astar: astar,
    Graph: Graph
};

});
```