# how to detect and move/drag the free flow drawn lines in html canvas?

Tags: javascript

My implementation is this:

1. Detect if mousedown and mousemove and if true then draw and saved the points in an array.
2. In my mousemove I will convert the points that will be drawn in
3. I converted the `curPath` to `(Date,value)` then to `(X and Y-axis`) so that they will be saved in the implementation in my canvas.

**My problem** is that how will I detect points[] ? so that I can highlight it and drag as well.

Comment: I assume this has to do with your [older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005977/how-to-detect-if-mouse-position-is-hovering/33006913#33006913), but I can't quite get what you want. Do you want to be able to drag the drawn points you get when hovering? Then what? You only want to move those points or draw a line to the next point or move the whole path or change the curve as if it were a cubicBezierCurve ? (Except the last one, all of these are quite simple now. For the last one, you'll have to rewrite everything.)

Comment: As @Kaiido asks...please clarify if you want to: (1) drag the whole polyline, (2) drag just one line segment on the polyline or (3) drag a vertex point on the polyline. The answers differ greatly depending on what you are seeking.

Comment: Blindman67 answer is spot on, but I'm thinking if there's any implication of boundingBox. For example if it will overlap with other previously created objects in the canvas

Comment: @ThomasM. Bounding boxes are not actually drawn on the canvas. They are just numeric representations of the rectangle which exactly encloses each freeform path -- they are the path's boundary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE.

This is bigger than I expected. I will continue to improve the quality of the answer as I go. See the bottom of the answer for status.

**Picking.**
The simplest way is to check how far the mouse is from each point in the line, and highlight the line that has the closest point. The problem is that when you have many lines and lots of points it slows down and become unusable.

Another ways is to store some extra info on each line to help you vet lines that are not going to be picked. In the example I create a bounding box for each line and check if the mouse is inside or near that box. If so then I search the line some more checking each line segment and keeping the line that is closest to the mouse.

Some of the function to look at.

```
Helpers.prototype.resetExtent();
Helpers.prototype.extent();
Helpers.prototype.copyOfExtent();
```

Used to find the bounding box. (extent)

```
function refreshLine(line);
```

Called after a line is drawn, it takes a set of points drawn and adds the bounding box (extent), plus other stuff for the demo.

```
function findLineAt(x,y){
```

This function takes the `x,y` position of the mouse (or what ever) and returns the closest line within 20 pixels. It first checks the bounding box, if that passes it calls

```
Helpers.prototype.getDistToPath = function (line,x,y) {
```

This gets the line as just a set of points and checks the distance to the center of each line. It also checks if the check needs more details and calls the function.

```
Helpers.prototype.distPointToLine = function (x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
```

This function will return the shortest distance from a point to a line. `x,y` is the point `x1,y1,x2,y2` is the line. It does not check the line segment but the line which is infinitely long. `Helpers.lineSegPos` property will hold the normalised position of the closest point on the line. If you need it.

So back to `findLineAt(x,y)`, after all those calls it will return the line if found or undefined if not.

**Highlight and dragging.**

Highlighting is up to you. I just cycle the hue of the line closest very quickly. You may wish to put a bounding box around it. Easy to do as all you do is redraw the closest line each update.

**How its works**

**The main loop.**
    update()

Handles the main loop, is called 60 times a second and has to parts, the Draw section is for drawing and pick for picking. See if(drawMode==="Pick"). The mouse is only read in the update, the mouse is set independently by the mouse listener. At the end of every loop I save the mouse button state `mouse.lastButton` so that I can check when the mouse moves down and up.

In the `pick` part if the mouse is not down I call the `findLineAt` function. If I find a line (line !== undefined) I highlight the line by changing its colour and drawing it.

Because every update I have the current mouseButton state and what it was last update, I will know when the mouse button first moves down because `mouse.button` is true and `mouse.lastButton` is false. If there is a line near the mouse, I record the mouse position in `dragOffX` and `dragOffY` and set a flag `dragging` to true. I also draw the canvas onto another canvas to keep as background. At this point I also check which mouse button is down. If right button I copy the line and set it as the line to be dragged, or if the middle button I search all the lines to find its index in the `lineArray` and delete it, then just redraw.

Next update (1/60th second later) and `dragging` flag is true `mouse.button` is true and `lastLine` (the line that was closest) is not undefined I know I am dragging a line. I clear the canvas, draw the saved copy of the canvas (it's faster to draw that then redraw all the lines again especially if you have 100's of lines with 1000's of points), and then redraw the line I am dragging.

To workout where to draw the dragged line I get the distance the mouse is from `dragOffX` and `dragOffY` and set the transpose part of `setTransform(1, 0 , 0, 1, mouse.x - dragOffX, mouse.y - dragOffY)` to that distance. That has the effect of moving the line by the drag amount. I keep doing this until the mouse button is up.

**Drop**
Next update and mouse.button is up. 
If the mouse button is up and the `dragging` flag is true then I must drop the line. At this point a get the mouse distance from `dragOffX` `dragOffY` and add it to each point in the line. Effectively moving the line. I also update the bounding box. I then clear the screen and redraw all the line, that removes the old position of the line from the canvas and put it at it's new home.

Done.

The code grew a little long. If this answer gets some support then I will clean it up some more. If not well then it does not matter..

It covers the basics of your question, detecting and moving points via mouse action. Highlighting and moving lines made of sets of points. My point are arrays of objects each with an x and y. Each line is stored in the `lineArray` a line has `style, extent, id` properties, and an array called `line` with all the points.

There is one mouse handler that takes the required mouse events. Move, mouse down and up, and mouse out. Mouse out stops the mouse locking up by turning the mouse buttons off. I also stop the context menu while the mouse is over the canvas.

I use requestAnimationFrame to call update to keep it all running smoothly.

I hope this helps you. I will improve it if it is what you are after. If not you will have to give a litte more info. Please do ask if you have problems.

Updates.
Added bounding box and improved the `Helpers.prototype.getDistToPath(line,x,y)` which I forgot to fix last night. Now its quicker and does not miss lines parallel to x and y axis. Moved screen redraw to accommodate the bounding box and add more comments.

Please do not hesitate to ask if you have question to this problem.

```js
function log(){}; // duck up the logs

customCursors ={
encoding:"url('data:image/png;base64,",
drag_small : {
    center : " 25 25,",
    image : "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADMAAAAzCAYAAAA6oTAqAAACQElEQVRoQ+2azW7DIAyAYZdJW6vlVmmnvcLe/yH2CjtN6i1Tu0m9rIMsJIYChmCvCWkuqZSA/fkPQyoF83VWl5RSqJtQd8kpjnVyB4QdiA0GghhvcHuIBcYH8h9A5DAxEG4gUhgN8rzbiY/9Hs1zjpAjg0nxiEtIDUQCMwWEI+SKYfJBzorDFkvloSvAXKZTs92K9nAoXlTJYFwV9YofunyNAEWHQALjU9qETijpA2OK9CkaHLJ8NYumBrzBoMss/sK6wkyHDLRJyp6EKsxyZUc9Y5R62mzE5/GYvB+hhNFVMVV+EMZVKGeVpoYxwYHp4IUp3VhxwehwjwFdwIQUwawC84oTJgZkwaQogRfIvzcA/DCkb1m63Eu9sE4CFqQBxgty+hLi/mHocnMOVyzFf96EuHv1AkKopmlE27YW5wiuDHD6Vvo8Ds/daOlggh7pYMbBqdaEnon9zpmve9ejDwSS0f3IRBgYGqOwF2W0dysEKWCskO4dkz1vbADMF9PaQ6OF8qBECT1ndZ6pJ2eMa6upZlGg/mFunF91ncGAFtcBxIDmApPVm4WA5gCD6bCO/Qz0EFzMFrvTnLoip3TfKUbJlb+uA41c60S7cPUQS+Ip8syYm2eg9dzjoMFK/edy19KxTqI0j4o9Y5LdVXqxXwFy+zYXfHbfZ9IPKWb85QyrXlh1oqxuxTmDdduJ22sSPUgmgUBV/A8gx0OUoWX1jVhMT3leVW8WKgpcHmFtZ3whxw2iZZIWAF9IOod/rPJ+AQ3iOFgpekFcAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC')"
},
}
function setCursor (name){
if(name === undefined){
    canvas.style.cursor = "default";
}
if(customCursors[name] !== undefined){
    var cur = customCursors[name];
    canvas.style.cursor = customCursors.encoding + cur.image + cur.center + " pointer";
}else{
    canvas.style.cursor = name;
}
}
// get canvas button and creat context2D
var canvas = document.getElementById("canV");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var but = document.getElementById("redrawAllID");
but.addEventListener("click",function(){
if(drawMode === "Pick"){
    drawMode = "Draw";
    but.value = "Draw Mode";
}else{
    drawMode = "Pick";
    but.value = "Pick Mode";
    lastLine = undefined;
    backGroundImage.ctx.clearRect(0,0,backGroundImage.width,backGroundImage.height);
    backGroundImage.ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
}
})
// Groover Bitmaps API dependency replacement
// Extracted from Groover.Bitmaps
var createImage= function(w,h){ // create a image of requier size
var image = document.createElement("canvas"); 
image.width = w;
image.height =h;
image.ctx = image.getContext("2d");  // tack the context onto the image
return image;
} 

var backGroundImage = createImage(canvas.width,canvas.height);
if(!mouse){
// get all the mouse events
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',mouseMoveEvent);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown',mouseMoveEvent);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup'  ,mouseMoveEvent);  
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout'  ,mouseMoveEvent);  
canvas.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){ e.preventDefault();}, false);

// helper for random colour
var mouse = {  // mouse data 
    x:0,
    y:0,
    button:false,
    lastButton:false,  // need this to see when the mouse goes down 
    which:[false,false,false],
};
}    
function mouseMoveEvent(event){// handle all canvas mouse events as they come in
// get new mouse positions
mouse.x = event.offsetX; 
mouse.y = event.offsetY; 
if(mouse.x === undefined){ // if firefox
    mouse.x = event.clientX;
    mouse.y = event.clientY;
}    
if(event.type === "mouseout"){
    mouse.button = false;
    mouse.which[0] = false;
    mouse.which[1] = false;
    mouse.which[2] = false;
}
if(event.type === "mousedown"){  // now see if there is extra info
    mouse.button = true;
    mouse.which[event.which-1] = true;
}
if(event.type === "mouseup"){  // now see if there is extra info
    mouse.button = false;
    mouse.which[event.which-1] = false;
}
event.preventDefault();
}

// because forEach is too slow
if (Array.prototype.each === undefined) {
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'each', {
    writable : false,
    enumerable : false,
    configurable : false,
    value : function (func) {
        var i,
        returned;
        var len = this.length;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            returned = func(this[i], i);
            if (returned !== undefined) {
                this[i] = returned;
            }
        }
    }
});
}
// helper functions
function Helpers(){
}
Helpers.prototype.randomColour = function(){
return "hsl("+Math.floor(Math.random()*360)+",100%,50%)";
}
Helpers.prototype.occilatingColour = function(){
var t = (new Date()).valueOf()
return "hsl("+(Math.floor(t/2)%360)+",100%,50%)";
}

// used for building up the extent of a cloud of points
Helpers.prototype.resetExtent = function(){
if(this.extentObj === undefined){  // check if the extentObj is there
    this.extentObj = {};  // if not create it
}
this.extentObj.minX = Infinity;
this.extentObj.minY = Infinity;
this.extentObj.maxX = -Infinity;
this.extentObj.maxY = -Infinity;
}
Helpers.prototype.extent = function( p) { // add a point to the extent
this.extentObj.minX = Math.min(this.extentObj.minX, p.x);
this.extentObj.minY = Math.min(this.extentObj.minY, p.y);
this.extentObj.maxX = Math.max(this.extentObj.maxX, p.x);
this.extentObj.maxY = Math.max(this.extentObj.maxY, p.y);
}
Helpers.prototype.copyOfExtent = function () {  // get a copy of the extent object
return {
    minX : this.extentObj.minX,
    minY : this.extentObj.minY,
    maxX : this.extentObj.maxX,
    maxY : this.extentObj.maxY,
    centerX : (this.extentObj.maxX-this.extentObj.minX)/2,
    centerY : (this.extentObj.maxY-this.extentObj.minY)/2,
    width:this.extentObj.maxX-this.extentObj.minX,
    height:this.extentObj.maxY-this.extentObj.minY,
};
}
Helpers.prototype.getID = function(){  // return a unique ID for this session
if(this.id === undefined){
    this.id = 0;
}
this.id += 1;
return this.id;
}
// function to get distance of point to a line
Helpers.prototype.distPointToLine = function (x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
var px = x2 - x1;
var py = y2 - y1;
var u = this.lineSegPos =  Math.max(0, Math.min(1, ((x - x1) * px + (y - y1) * py) / (this.distSqr1 = (px * px + py * py))));
return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x1 + u * px) - x, 2) + Math.pow((y1 + u * py) - y, 2));
}
// function to get the distance of a point to a set of point describing a line
Helpers.prototype.getDistToPath = function (line,x,y) {
var i,len, lineLen,dist;
len = line.length;
x1 = line[0].x;
y1 = line[0].y;
var minDist = Infinity;
for(i = 1; i < len-1; i++){
    var near = false;
    x2 =  line[i].x;
    y2 =  line[i].y;
    lineLen = Math.hypot(x1-x2,y1-y2);
    dist = Math.hypot((x1+x2)/2-x,(y1+y2)/2-y);
    minDist = Math.min(minDist,dist); 
    if(dist < lineLen ){
        minDist = Math.min(minDist,helpers.distPointToLine(x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2));
    }
    if(minDist < minDistToPass){
        return minDist;
    }
    x1 = x2;
    y1 = y2;
}
return minDist;
}
var helpers = new Helpers();
// Stuff for paths and drawing
var lineArray = [];  // list of paths
var lastLine; // last line drawn
var points;  // current recording path
var drawing = false;  // flag is mouse down and drawing
var dragging = false;
var dragOffX;
var dragOffY;
var drawMode = "Draw";
var minDistToPass = 2; // If a line is closer than this then stop search we found the winning line

// functions to redraw all recorded lines
function redrawAll(){  // style to draw in
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
lineArray.each(function(p){ // draw each one point at atime
    redraw(p,p.style);
})
}

// lineDesc is a line and its description
// style is a the style to draw the line in.
// withBox if true draw bounding box [optional]
function redraw(lineDesc,style,withBox){ // draws a single line with style
var line = lineDesc.line;
var len = line.length;
var i;
ctx.beginPath();   // 
ctx.strokeStyle = style.colour;  // set style and colour
ctx.lineWidth = lineDesc.style.width;
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.lineCap = "round";

ctx.moveTo(line[0].x,line[0].y);  // move to the first pont
for(i = 1; i < line.length; i++){   // lineto all the rest
    ctx.lineTo(line[i].x,line[i].y);
};
ctx.stroke(); // stroke
if(withBox){
    var w = Math.ceil(lineDesc.style.width/2); // need the lines width to expand the bounding box
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.strokeRect(  // draw the box around the line
        lineDesc.extent.minX-w,
        lineDesc.extent.minY-w,
        lineDesc.extent.width+w*2,
        lineDesc.extent.height+w*2
    )
}
// done
}

// Finds the closest line and returns it. If no line can be found it returns undefined.
function findLineAt(x,y){
var minDist = 20; // Set the cutoff limit. Lines further than this are ignored
var minLine;
var w;
lineArray.each(function(line){ // do ech line one at a time
    w = line.style.width;
    if(x >= line.extent.minX-w && x <= line.extent.maxX+w && // is the point inside the bounding
       y >= line.extent.minY-w && y <= line.extent.maxY+w){  // boc
        var dist = helpers.getDistToPath(line.line,x,y);  // if so then do a detailed distance check
        if(dist < minDist){   // is the distance to the line less than any other distance found
            minDist = dist;   // if so remember the line
            minLine = line;
        }
    }
    dist = Math.hypot(line.extent.centerX-x,line.extent.centerY-y); // check the distance to the 
    if(dist<minDist){                                               // center of the bounding boc
        minDist = dist;   // use this one if bound box center if close
        minLine = line;
    }
});
return minLine;
   
}
function refreshLine(line){ // updates the line to get extend and add stuff if needed
// a good place to smooth the line if need
if(!line.isLine){  
    var newLine = {};   // new object
    newLine.isLine = true; // flag to indicate that the line has been updated
    newLine.line = line;  // attach the line
    newLine.id = helpers.getID();   // get a unique Id for the line
    newLine.style = {  // give it a style
        colour:helpers.randomColour(),
        width:Math.random()*4+10,
    };
}else{
    var newLine = line;
}
var extent = helpers.extent.bind(helpers)
helpers.resetExtent();
line.each(extent);
newLine.extent = helpers.copyOfExtent();
return newLine;
}
function update(){  // one animframe
if(drawMode === "Draw"){
if(!mouse.lastButton && mouse.button ){ // if the mouse but just down;
    points = []; // create an new array     
    drawing = true; // flag drawinf

    lineArray.push(points);  // save the point array onto the pointsArray
    points.push({x:mouse.x,y:mouse.y}); // add the first point
    setCursor("none");
}else
if(drawing && mouse.button){  // while the mouse is down keep drawing
    points.push({x:mouse.x,y:mouse.y});  // save new point
    var p1 = points[points.length-2];  // get last line seg and draw it
    var p2 = points[points.length-1];
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(p1.x,p1.y);
    ctx.lineTo(p2.x,p2.y);
    ctx.stroke();
}else{
    if(drawing){ // if drawing and mouse up
        points.push({x:mouse.x,y:mouse.y}); // add the last point
        lineArray.push(points = refreshLine(lineArray.pop()))
        // redraw the newly draw line
        redraw(points,points.style);
        drawing = false; // flag that drawing is off.

    }else{
        setCursor("crosshair");
    }
}
}else
if(drawMode = "Pick"){
    if(!dragging && !mouse.button){  // is the mouse near a line and not dragging
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // clear background
        ctx.drawImage(backGroundImage,0,0);           // draw copy of existing lines
        var line = findLineAt(mouse.x,mouse.y);  // find the line 
        if(line !== undefined){   // is a line is near 
            setCursor("drag_small"); // highlight it
            lastLine = line;          // remember it
            // draw it hightlighted with bounding box.
            redraw(lastLine,{colour:helpers.occilatingColour(),width:lastLine.width},true);
        }else{
            setCursor();  // not near a line so turn of cursoe
        }
    }else  // next check if the mouse has jsut been click to start a drag.
    if(lastLine !== undefined && !mouse.lastButton && mouse.button){
        if(mouse.which[2]){  // Check which button. Right? then copy
            var newLine = [];
            lastLine.line.each(function(p){newLine.push({x:p.x,y:p.y})});
            newLine = refreshLine(newLine)
            newLine.style = lastLine.style;
            lastLine = newLine;
            lineArray.push(newLine)

        }else
        if(mouse.which[1]){ // Check which button. Middle? then delete
            var index;
            lineArray.each(function(line,i){
                if(line.id === lastLine.id){
                    index = i;
                }
            })
            if(index !== undefined){
                lineArray.splice(index,1);
            }
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            redrawAll();                
            lastLine = undefined;
            if(lineArray.length === 0){
                drawMode = "Draw";
                but.value = "Draw Mode";
            }
        }
        if(lastLine !== undefined){
            dragging = true;
            dragOffX = mouse.x;
            dragOffY = mouse.y;
           // backGroundImage.ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
           // backGroundImage.ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);
        }
    }else{
        if(dragging && !mouse.button){ // Drop is dragging true and not mouse down
            dragging = false;
            var ox = mouse.x-dragOffX;  // Find the drag offset
            var oy = mouse.y-dragOffY;
            helpers.resetExtent();     // get ready for new bounding box.
            lastLine.line.each(function(p){  // move each point of the line
                p.x += ox;
                p.y += oy;
                helpers.extent(p);  // and test the bounding box
                return p;
            })
            lastLine.extent = helpers.copyOfExtent();  // get the new boundong box
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
            redrawAll();
            backGroundImage.ctx.clearRect(0,0,backGroundImage.width,backGroundImage.height);
            backGroundImage.ctx.drawImage(canvas,0,0);                
        }else
        if(dragging){  // if dragging 
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // clear
            ctx.drawImage(backGroundImage,0,0);  // draw existing lines
            var ox = mouse.x-dragOffX;   // get the drag offset
            var oy = mouse.y-dragOffY;
            ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,ox,oy);  // translate by drag offset
            redraw(lastLine,lastLine.style);  //draw the dragged line
            ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);  // reset transform
        }
    }
}
mouse.lastButton = mouse.button; // set the last button state
window.requestAnimationFrame(update); // request a new frame
}
window.requestAnimationFrame(update)
```

```css
.canC {
    width:256px;
    height:256px;
    border:black 2px solid;
}
.info{
  font-size:x-small;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="redrawAllID" value="Click to Pick"></input>
<div class="info">Mouse down to draw.In pick mode mouse hover over line.<br> Left Button drag,middle delete, right copy.</div>
<canvas class="canC" id="canV" width=256 height=256></canvas>
```

Comment: Also, I think that OP already had [some code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005977/how-to-detect-if-mouse-position-is-hovering/33006913), but not sure though since he didn't talked about it in its today's post

Comment: @Kaiido I will fire up FF and see what the problem is and fix it. But its 12 midnight here so may have to do it in the morning if it will take some work.

Comment: @Kaiido Yes I tested it some months back and it was 3-4 times quicker than `Array.some` but things are changing quickly; I use it because I like the functionality of it, easy to change if needed.

Comment: **Firefox mouse bug fixed**

Comment: Dang totally forgot. The `getDistToPath` function should have dropped the bounding box test and used the distance from line center calculated after the bounding box test. To late to fix it now, will do it in morning.

Comment: I will try to understand and implement it.

Comment: Is there other solution that will not use bounding box?

Comment: @Thomas. What do you mean. You can just remove the bounding box test and call `Helpers.getDistToPath = function (line,x,y);` but that will slow down as the number of lines and point density start to rise.

Comment: I mean other approach. Btw is it necessary to use var createImage?

Comment: @Thomas There are other approaches. You can use the built in ctx.isPointOnPath() this is handy. I dont use this method because when you start to get very complex scenes, and or use images rather than redraw it does not work. No you don't have to use `createImage`, but you will then have to find another way of clearing the screen. Where every you see `ctx.drawImage(backgroundImage,0,0)` replace with `clearRect` and `redrawAll`. It will work just as well for a small number of lines.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I will try to do it in the next 5 hours and hopefully you are still in here if I'll encounter a problem.