# Using a SVG Path as a "skeleton" to another path (Bend path)

Tags: javascript, svg

I'm trying to achieve this bend effect on a path, This effect takes an existing path (skeleton) and allows one to “bend” it in a shape path. The style of the bent path is taken from the style of the original shape path.
like this [image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/20912155/81136484-1021aa80-8f32-11ea-8c81-5dca67107c2f.png)

can someone tell me a way to achieve this effect?
this deformation is used in the vector drawing tool Inkscape, which uses svg as a standard, and I would like to use animating with javascript and found this library [warp.js](https://github.com/benjamminf/warpjs), I am not sure how to try to implement this effect, any direction would be of great help.

The description of how the effect works is on this link
http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-BendTool.html
and here is the c ++ implementation of the bend tool, has a brief description of the theory from J.F. Barraud,
https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/blob/master/src/live_effects/lpe-bendpath.cpp

even with the description I couldn’t understand what to do as a starting point, any help is welcome

Comment: Generally speaking, these types of curves are known of as `splines` Curves can be of differing complexities, but these ones seem simple with only 3 or 4 control points affecting where each point on the spline lies. Here's another discussion on the matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054272/how-to-draw-smooth-curve-through-n-points-using-javascript-html5-canvas

Comment: I know how to create the paths, but not bend a path to follow another...