# Clip + Arc leads to an unwanted closing of the path, while Clip + Rect shows the expected behavior

Tags: html, html5-canvas

**Question:**

Why does `CanvasRenderingContext2D.clip()` closes an additional path when applying it to a collection of `CanvasRenderingContext2D.arc()` sampled along the path of a quadratic curve?

**Background**

I am trying to create a path of quadratic segments with a longitudinal color split. Based on a comment to the question "[Square curve with lengthwise color division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72384357/11918697)" I am trying to accomplish this goal by going through the following steps:

1. Draw the quadratic path
2. Sample point on the quadratic curve
3. Create a clipping region and draw a cycle at each sampled point

```js
let region = new Path2D();
for (j = 0; j < pointsQBez.length; j++) {
    region.arc(pointsQBez[j].x, pointsQBez[j].y, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI );
}
ctx.clip(region)
```

4. Split the canvas into two segments based on the curve

   1. Calculate the intersection of the start- and end-segment with the canvas border
   2. Close the path (first clipping region)
   3. Draw a rectangle over the whole canvas (second clipping region)
5. Fill in the two regions created in step four

Steps 3, 4, and 5 in pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Issue**

The pink part in the third image above should have the same thickness as the turquoise.
But for some strange reason, the whole inner part of the curve gets filled in.

**Additional observations**

1. This behaviour does not show when using `CanvasRenderingContext2D.rect()` instead of `CanvasRenderingContext2D.arc()`:

[image]
[image]
[image]

2. When using `CanvasRenderingContext2D.arc()`, the inner part of the curve that is filled in is not consistent

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `rect` does include a call to `closePath()` while `arc` doesn't.

Two ways of working around that:

You can call `closePath()` after each arc:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const pointsQBez = [];
const cx  = 75;
const cy  = 75;
const rad = 50;
for(let i = 0; i < 180; i++) {
  const a = (Math.PI / 180) * i - Math.PI / 2;
  const x = cx + Math.cos(a) * rad;
  const y = cy + Math.sin(a) * rad;
  pointsQBez.push({ x, y });
}

let region = new Path2D();
for (const {x, y} of pointsQBez) {
  region.arc(x, y, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  region.closePath();
}
ctx.clip(region);

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Or you can `moveTo()` the entry point of your arc:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const pointsQBez = [];
const cx  = 75;
const cy  = 75;
const rad = 50;
for(let i = 0; i < 180; i++) {
  const a = (Math.PI / 180) * i - Math.PI / 2;
  const x = cx + Math.cos(a) * rad;
  const y = cy + Math.sin(a) * rad;
  pointsQBez.push({ x, y });
}

let region = new Path2D();
for (const {x, y} of pointsQBez) {
  region.moveTo(x + 4, y); // x + arc radius
  region.arc(x, y, 4, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
}
ctx.clip(region);

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you very much! That helped me immensely. With the `closePath()` approach, I still saw some artifacts. But the `moveTo()` approach worked like a charm. Thanks also for adopting my nomenclature and providing such comprehensive examples!